# How to get more group matches after specific string?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

How it is possible to get more groups of regular expression?

I want to extract substrings of following string:

```
group g1 l1 l2 l3 g2 g3.l1
```

as groups. The output should include g1, l1, l2, l3, g2 and g3.l1.

I already tried to get these with regular expressions like this:

```
group (\S+)\s(\S+)*
```

My problem is, that I could get different groups with the group expression ( ), but I can get more or less of these substrings. My string also could like this: `group g1 g2.l1`

Comment: Could you provide an actual text example of a string you want to regex through and your desired output? I don't understand much from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern starts with matching `group` and then uses 2 capturing groups. You get only 2 groups because the repetition in the last group repeats matching only a non whitespace char `\S` and will not match a whitespace char.

If you would change that to `(\s\S+)*` you will repeat the capturing group capturing only the value of the last repetition.

What you might do is making use of `\G` to get repetetive matches by asserting the position at the end of the previous match

```
(?:^group |\G(?!^))(\S+)(?:\s+|$)
```

In java

```
String regex = "(?:^group |\\G(?!^))(\\S+)(?:\\s+|$)";
```

That will match

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^group` Match group and a space at the string of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of the previous match, not at the start of the string
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(\S+)` Capture in group 1 matching 1+ non whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+|$)` Match either 1+ whitespace chars or assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ja8W5/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/CcdSjY)

For example

```
String regex = "(?:^group |\\G(?!^))(\\S+)(?:\\s+|$)";
String string = "group g1 l1 l2 l3 g2 g3.l1";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result

```
g1
l1
l2
l3
g2
g3.l1
```

Comment: it is possible to extract these in different groups? I would like to get the first result as group 1 and the others as group 2

Comment: @Sony You might do that like this `^group (\S+)((?: \S+)*)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zrul9W/1/) and perhaps split group 2 on a space. Or in separate groups `(?:^group (\S+)|\G(?!^))\s(\S+)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zrul9W/2)

Answer (score 0):

If we wish to capture those alphanumerics, separated with an space, and capture the word `group` separately, we can design a simple expression using alteration:

```
(group|another_group)|([^\s]+)
```

which here we would simply pass group, or if any, other groups:

```
(group|another_group)
```

then we collect everything excluding spaces using:

```
([^\s]+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VeWRcX/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(group|another_group)|([^\\s]+)";
final String string = "group g1 l1 l2 l3 g2 g3.l1\n"
     + "another_group g1 l1 l2 l3 g2 g3.l1";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Note that your pattern will also match when `group` is not present because the alternation will match either group or not a whitespace character.